# Микросервисная архитектура laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, микросервисы

Решил попробовать использовать в проектах laravel микросервисную архитектуру. Но есть вопросы связанные с так называемым хабом (Проект который будет управлять запросами пользователя и вызывать необходимы микросервис). Возможно есть примеры того как такой хаб организовывается хотя бы на примере одного микросервиса с конкретным запросом.

Comment: https://github.com/Agaltsovd/laravel_faq_microservice